# Finding the order and computing the residue of a pole

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the poles, indicate their order and compute their residues for the following functions: $$g(z)=\frac{e^z}{\sin z}$$

I have a singularity at $z=0$ where the residue would be $1$ ... however, would I also have a pole at $z=n\pi$? If yes, how would I calculate the order and residue of this?

Comment: which residue theorem are you using?

Comment: for the singularity at $z=0$ i used limits

Comment: i used limits for the pole at $z=n\pi$ and got the residue as $\pm exp(n\pi)$ based on $n$ being even or odd .. would this be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are poles at $z=n \pi$ for all integer values of $n$ since $\sin (n\pi) =0$ for all integer $n$.

---

To show that the poles are simple, expand $\sin z$ in the series

$$\begin{align}
\sin z &=(-1)^{n} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{m} \frac{(z-n\pi)^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)!}\\\\
&=(-1)^{n} (z-n\pi) \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{m} \frac{(z-n\pi)^{2m}}{(2m+1)!}
\end{align}$$

where the last summation is not zero when $z=n\pi$.

---

To calculate the residues, we have

$$\lim_{z \to n \pi} (z-n\pi)\left(\frac{e^z}{\sin z}\right)=(-1)^ne^{n\pi}$$

Comment: thank you, would this be considered as a simple pole?

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure.  Yes, the poles are simple.